# use hiredis for node_redis

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-redis

I am using node_redis from https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

It says

> Pieter Noordhuis has provided a binding to the official hiredis C
>   library, which is non-blocking and fast. To use hiredis, do:
>
> npm install hiredis redis

I follow the instruction and compile hiredis, but I found that the hiredis.node is located in `/node_modules/hiredis/build/Release/hiredis.node`.

But node_redis is located at `/node_modules/redis`

I am afraid node_redis can find the hiredis.node C library.

**Question**:

1. How can I determine if node_redis is using hiredis as parser?
2. Should I move **hiredis.node** to `/node_modules/redis` directory?
3. Should I `yum install hiredis`? I am not sure if hiredis.node uses hiredis static library or dynamic library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation all you have to do is `npm install hiredis redis`

```
var client = redis.createClient(options);
console.log(client.reply_parser.name); // retrieve parser name
```

Check this [test file](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/benchmarks/multi_bench.js#L84) in benchmarks folder

**EDIT:**
you can pass parser in options, like they did in link above L27-31

```
var options = {
     parser: 'hiredis'
};
```